# TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of null

Tags: javascript, mongoose, userid

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of null

Listed both my `UserDB.js` and `profileController.js`, unsure of what this error is regarding. When I transition from my page and go to myItems(cart) it spits out this error.

```
router.get('/myItems', function(req, res, next){
res.locals.signin = req.session.signin;
var UserDB = require('../models/UserDB');
var Users = UserDB.getUser();
console.log(Users);
var LocalUser = Users.find(function (ele) {if (ele.userID === req.session.signin) {return ele;}});
if (SessionOn) {
    var UserProfiles = UserDB.GetUserProfiles();
    var LocalProfile = UserProfiles.find(function (ele) {if (ele.GetUserID() === LocalUser.userID) {return ele};});
}

res.render('myItems', {LocalUser: LocalUser, LocalProfile: LocalProfile, Session: res.locals.signin, SessionOn: SessionOn});
next()
});
```

*-------------------*

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/DB');
   var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var userDataSchema = new Schema({
    userID: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true},
    state: {type: String, required: true},
    zipCode: {type: String, required: true}

    },{collection: 'User'});

    var UserData = mongoose.model('User', userDataSchema);

    function getAllUsers(){
    try{
        return UserData.find({});
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    }

    function getUser(user){
    try{
        return  UserData.findOne({userID: user});

    }catch(e){
        console.log("error " + e);
    }
    }

    module.exports.getUser = getUser;
    module.exports.getAllUsers = getAllUsers;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mongoose model query function Users.find() gives you an array of objects
So if you want to Access it the way you have used
try like this

```
Users.findOne({userid:xxx},callback);
```

or you have to access the array index if you use it find() method

```
Users.find({userId:xxx},(users)=>{users[0]==neededId}
```